# Getting child of child PHP

Tags: php, parent-child

How can I get child of child? 
But not the childs, only the child of the child.

ex.
You have a domain whose name is "blabla.com"
You have a page, which has the name of frontpage ( A ).
There are links to child pages, name of them are B 1,2,3,.. So on.

And in those child pages are more child pages, name is C 1,2,3,.. So on.

But I want to show not only the links to the child ( B ) pages, but also to the child of the child pages ( C ). At a different spot of the page A.

So I want page A to show B&C links, but in a different spot.

I am using Wordpress. I need to get the child pages as links, to my page A, and also the page B's siblings to my page A.

```
<?php 

$child_pages = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_parent = ".$post->ID." AND post_type = 'page' ORDER BY menu_order", 'OBJECT');

if ( $child_pages ) :
    foreach ( $child_pages as $pageChild ) :
        setup_postdata( $pageChild );
        $thumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail($pageChild->ID, 'thumbnail', true);
        if ($thumbnail == "") continue; // Skip pages without a thumbnail
        $thumbShort = explode('src="', $thumbnail);
        $thumbnailShortStripped = substr($thumbShort[1], 0, strpos( $thumbShort[1], '"'));
?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?= get_permalink($pageChild->ID) ?>" rel="bookmark">
                <img src="<?= $thumbnailShortStripped; ?>" class="thumbnail" alt="<?= $pageChild->post_title ?>" 0="" />
            </a>
        </li>
<?
    endforeach;
endif;
?>
```

This is the code I am using now for retrieving childs to my page.

Comment: What do you mean, by finite?

Comment: Hum. Never worked with the DOM with PHP, but you should take a look at DOMDocument. http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand. Does this relate to retrieving records from a DB, or manipulation of existing content within the DOM?

Comment: I just edited that a little bit. So I need the wordpress to get me the names of the child pages and the thumbnails. And this childs childs, you know? 
Holy crap it's hard to explain. I just need the child's of the child's links to show.

Comment: You should include some code so your question doesn't get closed. As it is, it's really unclear what you're on about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all, I figured it out my self!

```
<?
$child_pages = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_parent = ".$post->ID." AND post_type = 'page' ORDER BY menu_order", 'OBJECT');
$i = 0;
if ( $child_pages ) :
foreach ( $child_pages as $pageChilds ) :
    $gchild_pages = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_parent = ".$pageChilds->ID." AND post_type = 'page' ORDER BY menu_order", 'OBJECT');
    if($gchild_pages) :
    foreach ($gchild_pages as $pageChild):
    setup_postdata( $pageChild );
    $thumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail($pageChild->ID, 'thumbnail', true);
    if($thumbnail == "") continue; // Skip pages without a thumbnail

?>
    <a href="<?= get_permalink($pageChild->ID) ?>" rel="bookmark">
       <div class="child-thumb">
      <li> <?= $thumbnail ?></li>
       <div class="child-text"><?= $pageChild->post_title ?></div>
       </div>
    </a>
<?

    endforeach;
    endif;
endforeach;
endif;
?>
```

Thanks!

-Kev